# How can I show face Recognition window( code written in python using dlib,opencv) in my web application

Tags: php, python, opencv

I have a php web application for registration. In this application I am also storing face data of person into database along with all the other information.
For face data I am using python  (dlib and opencv) . I am executing this python   file using ajax call through php. when I am executing this python then a separate window is opening for face recognition.

I want to open this window inside one of html tag in php application .

Comment: Have you tried anything? Any code to present or references?

Comment: I don't have any idea about this So I did't try ..!!

Comment: So please tell me how can i do this If you have any idea .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a web application, you would need a javascript + HTML + CSS front end.
I don't know if you would need to rewrite your python code in javascript, or possibly just use javascript to send image data to your python code.

If you want to rewrite in js, check out the [OpenCV.js](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d10/tutorial_js_root.html) library.

Or, as I'm not sure of the details, you might want to take a picture of the user and send it to the server to run in your python.  You can use the WebRTC API, with `navigator.getUserMedia` to take a photo with the user's web camera (I think, the last time I looked into that the API was changing fast - but a google search for those terms should get you in the right direction)

Comment: Hi Michael thanks for your response , Here I am saving person's name,DOB,age,salary and face binary code into database, So for face binary code I am calling php file through ajax  in which I am executing python file and return back face binary code.

Comment: oh, I see, you don't need to get face data from the user, you already have that stored, right?  Then you just need to display that face data on the front end?